# a version of taylor theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I need to a version Taylor theorem (Taylor expantion) in $H^2(0,1)$.
What is the difference between it and usual Taylor expantion.

Where can I find it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $H^2(0,1)$, and why would a Taylor expansion there be any  different than the usual one?

Comment: $H^2(0,1)$ is a sobolev space that is the space of all functions where are in $L^2(0,1)$ and  also their first and second derivatives in the weak sence. It is my homework on approximation theory

Comment: Do you want a Taylor expansion of a function in $H^2(0,1)$ or of a function mapping $H^2(0,1)$ into $\mathbb R$ (or another space)?

Comment: I need a Taylor expantion of a function in $H^2(0,1)$

Answer (score 2):

Since the second weak derivative of a function $f \in H^2$ is only in $L^2$ (and therefore, defined only up to a null set), you cannot expect a (pointwise) second order taylor expansion to be valid.

However, since $H^2(0,1)$ embeds into $C^1([0,1])$, you can use a first order taylor expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I think Taylor expansion is true a.e. If $\phi \in C^\infty_c(0,1) $ is a test function then we have $ \phi(x-h) = \phi(x) -h\phi'(x) + (h^2/2) \phi''(x) + o(h^2) $. Integrating after multiplying with $f$ we have 
$$ \int f(x)\phi(x-h)dx = \int f(x)\phi(x)dx - h\int f(x)\phi'(x)dx + (h^2/2)\int f(x)\phi''(x)dx + o(h^2) $$
Now if $f_1 $ and $f_2$ are weak derivatives of $f$ then with a change of variable in LHS above for small enough $h$ we can have
$$ \int f(x+h)\phi(x)dx = \int f(x)\phi(x) dx + h\int f_1(x)\phi(x) dx + (h^2/2)\int f_2(x)\phi(x) dx + o(h^2)$$
So $ f(x+h) = f(x) + hf_1(x) + (h^2/2)f_2(x) + o(h^2)$ a.e

Comment: A problem in your proof is, that the $o(h^2)$ depends on $\phi$ (in particular, on the norm of its third derivative). Hence, your conclusion is not valid.